# is my fast broken if i might have had dry sperm

Tags: sunni, ramadan, muslim-practices, islamic-scholar

when i woke up my penis was hard i went to eat suhoor but i felt something in my penis so i went to check and there was nothing in my underwear so i went to pee and i noticed white dry tiny things right next to my penis hole (may have been dry sperm, they also disappeared after peeing) so i spent 2 hours searching what it is, then there was 5 mins before fajr so i prayed it thinking because there was nothing in my underwear i was fine but now i’m thinking that the white stuff may have been dry cum does this invalidate the fast?

Comment: Why should it invalidate fast?

Comment: i thought it might but after talking to someone who specializes sex ed they told me that if there was no sign of pre ejaculate or ejaculate in the underwear there’s no way for dry sperm to form

Answer (score 1):

Your fast is only broken if you had intercourse or semen emission by any means while fasting (not between maghrib and fajr). As fast means to refrain from eating drinking and sexual desires for a defined period of time of the day.